# Does this count as a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: probability, statistics, monte-carlo

Let's say I have a group of robots that walk on a 11x11 grid of tiles in four directions, N, S, E, W, and each robot has different probability distribution functions that assign different probabilities to each of the four outcomes per move.

If I want to know how many moves it will take on average for each robot to exit the grid and also how often on average it will exit on a particular side (N S E W), and so I run a simulation for 1000s of iterations for each robot to determine mean averages, does this count as a Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: Sure, why not? And if the robots don't interfere with each other's paths, then the simulations are independent and can be run serially (or parallel) just vary the directional parameters.

Comment: Yes, this is MC.